# Rosserial make_libraries missing custom message

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting into ROS and rosserial for my robot, which will use an Arduino for low level processing. Creating a custom message is important, but so far I've hit a roadblock in which rosserial cannot generate the header file for my custom message.

I've been following the tutorials to create and build .msg files and after it all, rosmsg can find and display my messages correctly. However if I run make_libraries, only the standard messages from ROS are installed.

```
~/ros_workspace$ rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py ~/sketchbook/libraries

Exporting to ~/sketchbook/libraries
[my_project]: Not found
...
```

The end result only says messages could not be generated for map_msgs, and does not include my package. I suspect I'm missing a source command somewhere, but my familiarity with ROS prevents me from knowing when and which folder to run it. Any help greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129701/rosserial-make_libraries-missing-custom-message/) by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means one of the dependencies of my_project could not be found, check that all dependencies that you have in your package.xml are actually installed on the system.

I've just opened a pull request to add better error messaging for this: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/99

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0